# Animating a View In React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a simple application with navigation and one component.

```js
export default function App() {

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();

  return (

      <NavigationContainer>

            <Logo/>

            <Stack.Navigator>

                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen}/ >

            </Stack.Navigator>

      </NavigationContainer>

  );

}
```

The HomeScreen component has a simple fade animation that trigger when the application starts.

```js
export const HomeScreen = ({navigation})=>{

    const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        Animated.timing(
          fadeAnim,
          {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 350,
          }
        ).start();
      }, [fadeAnim]);

    return (
        <Animated.View style={{opacity: fadeAnim}} >
            <Text>
                Hello World
            </Text>
        </Animated.View>
    )
    
  }
```

The problem is that the `fadeAnim` animation does NOT restart when the view changes. Loading the "details" screen and then the "home" screen again finds the component in its final state.

How can I make the "home" screen fade in every time?

Not sure if the right solution is with `react-native` or `react-native-navigation`, but a solution involving either would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try using useFocusEffect

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen() {
  const [fadeAnim] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      Animated.timing(
        fadeAnim,
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 350,
        }
      ).start();
    }, [fadeAnim])
  );

  return yourComponents;
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be such an export from `@react-navigation/native` 


`import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native'`

`react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.useFocusEffect is not a function`

Comment: Check the docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/). I'm not sure I can help you too much more, as you're using a non-stardard setup (webpack)

Comment: This is the expo based set up which I think is the 2nd most common after React CLI, thanks anyways